# Is Google Spring Cloud GCP compatible with spring boot 3.0.0?

Tags: spring-boot, google-vision, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm using Google Spring Cloud GCP and getting errors since trying to upgrade spring boot 2.x.x to 3.x.x

> Description:
>
> Parameter 2 of constructor in x.MyService required a bean of type
> 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision.CloudVisionTemplate'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision.CloudVisionTemplate'
> in your configuration.

I am not facing this issue on spring boot 2.7.x. I found this table (linked below) so my understanding is that the latest Google Spring Cloud are not compatible with Spring Boot 3.x.x. Just wondering if anyone else is having the same issue?

[image: Compatibility with Spring Project Versions]

Answer (score 1):

According to https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Spring Cloud 2022.0.x aka Kilburn is compatible with Spring Boot 3.0.x

But:

> Spring Cloud GCP is no longer part of the Spring Cloud release train.
> The new repository location is
> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp. If you are
> upgrading from version 1.x, take a look at the migration guide to
> upgrade from version 1.x to 2.0.0 (or later).

And according to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp there is no Spring Boot 3 version available.